# Trying to list streaks of dates in Postgres DB in a textual context

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with a Date column, that is used to store data if a user has completed an event for the day:

| completed_date |
| --- |
| 2023-09-23 |
| 2023-09-21 |
| 2023-09-20 |
| 2023-09-03 |
| 2023-09-04 |
| 2023-09-05 |
| 2023-09-06 |
| 2023-09-10 |
| 2023-09-11 |

I need to be able to retrieve date streaks (including just a single day streak) in the following form:

1 Day  .... 23/Sept

2 Days .... 20/Sept - 21 Sept

2 Days .... 10/Sept - 11/Sept

4 Days .... 3/Sept - 6/Sept

I have tried all sorts of combinations of nested CTE's, and been hammering away for over a week without getting close to success, even though I am aware of the concepts of islands and seas, and been through lots of examples here about consecutive date ranges, but they all seem to cover identifying streaks but not being able to list them accurately.

I am using Postgres version 15.1

The best I have come up with so far is:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte
AS
(
    select completed_date, 1 as cnt, array [completed_date::date] as dates
    FROM schedule_completed 
    UNION ALL
    select a.completed_date, c.cnt + 1, array_append(dates, a.completed_date )
    FROM schedule_completed a inner JOIN cte c
    ON  a.completed_date = c.completed_date - interval '1' day 
),
cte2 AS
(select distinct cnt, completed_date as start_date, completed_date + interval '1' day * (cnt - 1) as end_date, dates  from cte order by cnt desc)

select * from cte2
```

which returns:

| cnt | start_date | end_date | dates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2023-09-03 | 2023-09-06 00:00:00 | 2023-09-06,2023-09-05,2023-09-04,2023-09-03 |
| 3 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-06 00:00:00 | 2023-09-06,2023-09-05,2023-09-04 |
| 3 | 2023-09-03 | 2023-09-05 00:00:00 | 2023-09-05,2023-09-04,2023-09-03 |
| 2 | 2023-09-20 | 2023-09-21 00:00:00 | 2023-09-21,2023-09-20 |
| 2 | 2023-09-03 | 2023-09-04 00:00:00 | 2023-09-04,2023-09-03 |
| 2 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-05 00:00:00 | 2023-09-05,2023-09-04 |
| 2 | 2023-09-10 | 2023-09-11 00:00:00 | 2023-09-11,2023-09-10 |
| 2 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-06 00:00:00 | 2023-09-06,2023-09-05 |
| 1 | 2023-09-23 | 2023-09-23 00:00:00 | 2023-09-23 |
| 1 | 2023-09-03 | 2023-09-03 00:00:00 | 2023-09-03 |
| 1 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-05 00:00:00 | 2023-09-05 |
| 1 | 2023-09-10 | 2023-09-10 00:00:00 | 2023-09-10 |
| 1 | 2023-09-21 | 2023-09-21 00:00:00 | 2023-09-21 |
| 1 | 2023-09-06 | 2023-09-06 00:00:00 | 2023-09-06 |
| 1 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-04 00:00:00 | 2023-09-04 |
| 1 | 2023-09-11 | 2023-09-11 00:00:00 | 2023-09-11 |
| 1 | 2023-09-20 | 2023-09-20 00:00:00 | 2023-09-20 |

As you can see, it isn't pretty!  The 2nd Line (3 dates) shouldn't be there as its a data subset of line 1 (4 dates), the same as line 5 (2 dates) its a subset of line 1 and line 2.

I am totally stuck !!